# the fastest serial port communication possible in C#?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am new at this forum and I do not have many experiences with programming in C#. I have build simple Windows application in C# to communicate with some electronic board that my friend gave it to me. He has defined serial port baud rate in microcontroller at 38400. I want to send and receive bytes via serial port as fast as possible. With existing serialport tool in C# I was able only to read bytes but still not fast enough even with eventhandler in its own thread. My buffer[4096] was full in few seconds.

My question is if there exist some other functions or tools for serial port communication that does not use so much processor time. I need to read one byte in less than 200 us. I have more experiences with embedded systems where this was not a problem.

Thanks everyone for some advice or idea.

Tomaž

Comment: Can you post your code? There should be no reason that your application can't handle 38400 with both hands tied behind its back and blindfolded.

Comment: 200us per byte is 5000bps - at 38400baud you are almost ten times faster than your stated requirement.  Is the problem latency and not throughput?

Comment: See also : [If you *must* use .NET System.IO.Ports.SerialPort](http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport).

Comment: 38400 is very fast, you could try 119200, but the board needs to be set to this baud as well.  The PC and the board both have to match baud rates.

Comment: @Baddack Cabling and environmental noise are also important - the faster the rate, the better the cables need to be and the lower the tolerance for noise.  I have systems in an (electrically noisy) industrial environment that run at 9600baud for this reason - at 38400, even, they will start to drop bytes randomly.  When doing any sort of development I will usually write and debug with the hardware, whenever possible, at 9600baud until everything is established and working.  Then you can start turning up the speed (in the operating environment) until you run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all replies. I can read all bytes coming from board, but I can not reply fast enough. Here is my code. I have used an event for reading buffer. If I try to reply in event the next bytes contains wrong values.

```
#region namespace usings
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

using Microsoft.Win32;
using Zaber.Serial.Core;
using Diagnostics = System.Diagnostics;
#endregion
```

namespace Lucifire_aplication
{

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{


    int k = 1;
    string number_of_bytes;
    byte checksum;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[11];
    byte[] buffer_old = new byte[11];


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        configure_button.Enabled = false;
        start_button.Enabled = false;
        foreach (string s in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
        {
            serial_port_name.Items.Add(s);
        }
        serial_port_name.Text = "Select port";
        for (int i = 4800; i <= 38400; i = i * 2)
        {
            baud_rate.Items.Add(i);
        }
        for (int i = 57600; i <= 921600; i = i * 2)
        {
            baud_rate.Items.Add(i);
        }

        serial_port_name.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        baud_rate.SelectedIndex = 3;
        baud_rate.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;


    }

    private void serial_port_name_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (serial_port_name.Text != "Select port")
        {
            configure_button.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void configure_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort1.PortName = serial_port_name.Text;
        serialPort1.BaudRate = Int32.Parse(baud_rate.Text);
        serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
        serialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        //serialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        serialPort1.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 44;
        serialPort1.ReadBufferSize = 8192;
        MessageBox.Show("Communication is set on " + serialPort1.PortName + " with baud rate: " + serialPort1.BaudRate);
        start_button.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void start_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {

            serialPort1.Close();
            start_button.Text = "START";
            read_button.Enabled = false;
            //read_write.Enabled = false;
            comport_status.Text = "DISCONNECTED";
        }
        else
        {
            serialPort1.Open();
            start_button.Text = "STOP";
            read_button.Enabled = true;
            //read_write.Enabled = true;
            comport_status.Text = "CONNECTED";
        }
    }

    private void quitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
    }

    private void read_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bytes_to_read.Text = serialPort1.BytesToRead.ToString();
        read_data.Text = serialPort1.ReadExisting().ToString();
        read_data.Text += k.ToString() + "   ";
        if (buffer_old[0] == 4)
        {
            serialPort1.ReadByte();
        }
        serialPort1.Read(buffer, 0, 11);
        for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++)
        {
            read_data.Text += buffer[j].ToString() + "  ";
        }
        read_data.Text += "\n";
        k++;
        buffer_old = buffer;
    }

    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        serialPort1 = (SerialPort)sender;
        number_of_bytes = serialPort1.BytesToRead.ToString();
        if (buffer_old[0] == 4)
        {
            serialPort1.ReadByte();
        }
        serialPort1.Read(buffer, 0, 11);
        buffer_old = buffer;
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(displaytext));
        Thread.Sleep(20);
    }

    private void displaytext(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checksum = 0;
        bytes_to_read.Text = number_of_bytes;
        read_data.Text += k.ToString() + "\t";
        for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++)
        {
            read_data.Text += buffer[j].ToString() + "  ";
            checksum += buffer[j]; 
        }
        checksum -= buffer[10];
        read_data.Text += "  \t" + checksum.ToString();
        read_data.Text += "\n";
        k++;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at :
[If you *must* use .NET System.IO.Ports.SerialPort](https://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport)

Ben Voigt (the author) gives an excellent example on how to use the inherent `BaseStream` member of `SerialPort` which is more efficient for using the underlying Win32 API.

```
Port = new SerialPort("COM" + PORT_NUMBER.ToString()); 
...
private void ReadEvent()  
{      
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2000];  
    Action kickoffRead = null;  
    kickoffRead = (Action)(() => Port.BaseStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, delegate(IAsyncResult ar)  
    {  
        try  
        {  
            int count = Port.BaseStream.EndRead(ar);  
            byte[] dst = new byte[count];  
            Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, dst, 0, count);  
            RaiseAppSerialDataEvent(dst);  
        }  
        catch (Exception exception)  
        {  
            MessageBox.Show(ERROR == > " + exception.ToString());    
        }  
        kickoffRead();  
    }, null)); kickoffRead();  
}
```

Regards.

Comment: That's not Vishal's code, it is mine (except for the first line and the MessageBox call).  Please update your attibution to https://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport  Ironically this correct original blog post was linked in the comments of this question 4 years ago...

Answer (score 0):

Like you, I was associated with a microcontroller with a C # program. In my sample, the microcontroller sent 2000 packets per second sent to PC and each packet was 18 bytes (Total 36000 bytes per second recieved). each packet included a header and footer and information such as voltage and current. I followed the following method and answered:

```
_serialPort = new SerialPort(_portName, _boudRate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
_serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
_serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);
_serialPort.ReadBufferSize = 100;
private List<byte> totalRecieved = new List<byte>();

private void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    int count = _serialPort.BytesToRead;
    byte[] recievedTemp = new byte[count];
    _serialPort.Read(recievedTemp, 0, count);
    totalRecieved.AddRange(recievedTemp);
    findPacket();
}

int findPacket(int index = 0, bool headerFounded = false)
{
    while (index + 1 < totalRecieved.Count)
    {
        if (totalRecieved[index] == 83 && totalRecieved[index + 1] == 84)
        {
            int headerIndex = index;
            int packetLen = 14;
            int footerIndex = findPacket(index + 2 + packetLen, true);
            if (footerIndex > -1 && (packetLen == 0 || (footerIndex == headerIndex + packetLen + 2)))
            {
                List<byte> data = totalRecieved.GetRange(headerIndex + 2, footerIndex - (headerIndex + 2));
                totalRecieved.RemoveRange(headerIndex, footerIndex + 2 - headerIndex);
                if (headerIndex > 0 && !headerFounded)
                    totalRecieved.RemoveRange(0, headerIndex);
                usePacket(data);
                continue;
            }
            else if (footerIndex != -1)
            { index++; continue; }
            break;
        }
        if (headerFounded && totalRecieved[index] == 69 && totalRecieved[index + 1] == 78)
            return index;
        index++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```