# C# - Grabbing data from serialport becomes too slow above 200kb/s

Tags: c#, serial-port

I created a wpf application to control and monitor a sensor invented at my university. I connect to the device with 2 comports of which one is exclusively for sending data from the device. The device encodes each dataset to 5 bytes and starts sending them as soon as I give it the order via the other comport. Internally the sensor has a buffer of ~40 kilobytes.

**Problem:**
It works very will until a sampling rate above 25kHz (25000 times 5 bytes each second) is chosen. Then data seems to be lost and the device sends an error, that the internal buffer ran full (which explains the lost data)

I tried several approaches without success yet, the latest was trying to apply this solution: https://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport

I fail to understand what determines how often I receive an event that grabs the data from the serialport. The problem doesn't change whether my program is fast or slow .. always ~25kHz = ~200kBytes/s

**Code:**

```
private SerialPort _comPortData; 
_comPortData.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(PortDataReceived);
```

The Connect() function, stripped-down:

```
void connect()  
{
   comPort.BaudRate = 115200;
   comPort.DataBits = 8;
   comPort.StopBits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), "One");
   comPort.Parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), "None");
   comPort.PortName = port;
   comPort.Open();
   Console.WriteLine(comPort.PortName + " opened | Baud Rate: " + comPort.BaudRate);
}
```

The (edited) PortDataReceived function:

```
private void PortDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!_comPortData.IsOpen) return;
        // Obtain the number of bytes waiting in the port's buffer
        int numberOfBytes = _comPortData.BytesToRead;
        // Create a byte array buffer to hold the incoming data

        byte[] buffer = new byte[numberOfBytes];
        // Read the data from the port asynchronously and store it in the buffer
        await _comPortData.BaseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, numberOfBytes);

        }
```

Comment: If using `BeginRead` and `EndRead` you don't need (and shouldn't use) the `DataReceived` event.

Comment: Okay, I guess I misunderstood how the linked approach works. Would explain why I didnt have any change in behavior in my program. I didn't realize yet where to invoke the code inside the "PortDataReceived" handler. I read through it again. Thank you!

Comment: You have set your baud rate to 115200.  At this speed you cannot read more than 115200/50 = 2304 samples per second.  Any additional will begin to fill up the onboard FIFO buffer.  A 40 kB buffer will hold about 8000 samples which at 25 ksps will take you about 1/3 second to overflow.

Comment: FWIW, that page you linked to has plagiarized my sample code for reading from serial port without (broken!) DataReceived event.  Please also read the original https://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware. Thanks a lot for your help and I make sure your code is linked! I got it from this question on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38313567/the-fastest-serial-port-communication-possible-in-c

Comment: From the post above by @BenVoigt, I'd strongly suggest you to pay attention at the last remarks, and use the Async methods, like `await _comPortData.BaseStream.ReadAsync(...)`.

Comment: That's how I approached it before and it doesn't change the problem (but helps optimizing of course). I think @BenVoigt's comment is the right direction but I fail to understand why it is so slow? I read that I could set the baudrate to 256000 but it would still be far away from what a serialport (USB 2.0) should be capable. I just want to get data with maximum 500kilobyte/s, isn't the serialport capable of like 30megabyte/s?